# How to calibrate Stereo Camera?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am using Snapdragon_Dev_Board(eagle8074/Snapdragon801) with Stereo Camera.
Snapdragon_Dev_Board has Linux Linaro 14.04(pre-loaded). I have installed ROS-Indigo on top of it.
I am running two nodes
**snap_cam_ros**
https://github.com/ATLFlight/snap_cam_ros
and **dfs_ros_example**
https://github.com/ATLFlight/dfs-ros-example

to get the disparity image, depth image and point cloud.

While I am launching the snap_cam_ros on [Snapdragon_Dev_Board + Linux Linaro 14.04(pre-loaded) + ROS-Indigo] environment , using:
`roslaunch snap_cam_ros stereo.launch`

it is showing the following error:

[ INFO] [7122.158294089]: using default calibration URL
[ INFO] [7122.159528307]: camera calibration URL: file:///camera_info/left.yaml
[ INFO] [7122.160654714]: Unable to open camera calibration file [/camera_info/left.yaml]
[ WARN] [7122.161524713]: Camera calibration file /camera_info/left.yaml not found.
[ INFO] [7122.162679974]: using default calibration URL
[ INFO] [7122.163516068]: camera calibration URL: file:///camera_info/right.yaml
[ INFO] [7122.164247578]: Unable to open camera calibration file [/camera_info/right.yaml]
[ WARN] [7122.164905130]: Camera calibration file /camera_info/right.yaml not found.
How to resolve this error: Can anyone help me out?
Regards,
Parwana Shahdi

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276108/how-to-calibrate-stereo-camera?/) by [Parwana Shahdi](https://answers.ros.org/users/32653/parwana-shahdi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-11-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Size of the checkerboard can be anything that you print out. As long as it is suitable enough to cover the entire stereo overlap region to get a good estimate of size but also provides enough samples along the x and y directions as well as skew samples. Print out whatever checkerboard works for you and then measure the square length and input that to your calibrator.

You can use the `camera_calibration` package which has a good tutorial

---

Originally posted by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) with karma: 1133 on 2017-11-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Parwana Shahdi](https://answers.ros.org/users/32653/parwana-shahdi/) on 2017-11-23**:
Thanks;
I did:
'roslaunch snap_cam_ros stereo.launch`
I am finding the following error:
using default calibration URL
camera calibration URL: file:///camera_info/left.yaml
Unable to open camera calibration file [/camera_info/left.yaml]
Camera calibration file /camera_info/left.yaml not found.